# Retroactively moving comments to chat, when they are no longer relevant, due to edit

Tags: support, comment, chat

In [a recent question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909538/why-does-this-algorithm-give-the-beta-distribution-in-the-limit-considering-len), @Ian and I had a rather lengthy back-and-forth about the meaning of something in my question that was unclear. At the time I deemed it relevant to keep in the comments, as others might have had similar issues understanding what I meant.

In the end, however, we figured out a much clearer formulation that I then implemented, leaving the 20-or-so comments obsolete. Now I feel like the comments-section is completely confusing for people trying to figure out the history of the question (and possibly answering it).

*Is it possible to migrate the now out-dated comments to the chat? Should I rather contact @Ian and ask him if he could delete his comments (whereafter I would delete mine)? Or should I perhaps make an edit in the question saying that the first 20-or-so comments can be ignored?*

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the [tag:feature-request] tag, because you were not really asking for a new feature to be added to the site SW.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Speaking of tags, (support) is probably more appropriate here than (discussion), isn't it? (If not, feel free to rollback my retag.)

Comment: You could always flag one of the comments for moderator attention, and explain that the exchange of comments was obsolete and best deleted.

Comment: Related older post: [How can I move from comment to chat?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11883/how-can-i-move-from-comment-to-chat)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done. Long comment exchanges (>20 comments) raise an automated flag that moderators then tend to. I am not familiar with the details of how soon such flags are raised. In this case I didn't wait for the flag and just did it. It is something like 2 mouse-clicks for a diamond bearer.

Creating a chatroom is better than deleting the comments in the sense that  any interested party can then view the removed material in the chatroom.

I undeleted Did's comment, because I wasn't sure your intention was to include that in the removal. Oops. Looks like Did was awake, and moved to correct things himself.

---

Usually there is no pressing need to make requests like this in meta. Long comment exchanges in main get flagged and relocated to chatrooms "invisibly" as a part of routine moderation.